# Is there any way of uploading large files with the ruby google drive api?

Tags: ruby, google-api

I was trying to upload a very large file (15GB) to google drive using the ruby's google-api-client, but I get a transmission error. Reading the documentation suggest you should be able to make the upload resumable by allowing for retries. But the upload fails even when using the max number of retries. Below is my attempt. Does anyone have any experience with this? It seems there isn't any helpful info about the ruby version of the google client.

```
file = Google::Apis::DriveV2::File.new(title: zip_name,parents:[parent_folder])
      uploaded_file = service.insert_file(file, upload_source: zip_name, content_type: 'application/zip',supports_all_drives:true,options: { retries: 2**24 })
```

This also fails with the V3 version of the API.

```
file = Google::Apis::DriveV3::File.new(title: zip_name,parents:[parent_folder])
      uploaded_file = service.create_file(file, upload_source: zip_name, content_type: 'application/zip',supports_all_drives:true,options: { retries: 2**24 })
```

Both yield this error

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/buffering.rb:324:in `syswrite': execution expired (Google::Apis::TransmissionError)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/buffering.rb:324:in `do_write'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/buffering.rb:342:in `write'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:80:in `<<'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/http.rb:582:in `dump_file'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/http.rb:508:in `dump'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/http.rb:962:in `dump'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:517:in `block in query'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:515:in `query'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:177:in `query'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1242:in `do_get_block'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1019:in `block in do_request'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1133:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1014:in `do_request'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1104:in `follow_redirect'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:854:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:765:in `post'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client-0.52.0/lib/google/apis/core/upload.rb:232:in `send_upload_command'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client-0.52.0/lib/google/apis/core/upload.rb:258:in `execute_once'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client-0.52.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:61:in `block in retriable'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `times'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `retriable'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client-0.52.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:110:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:61:in `block in retriable'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `times'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/retriable-3.1.2/lib/retriable.rb:56:in `retriable'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client-0.52.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:102:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client-0.52.0/lib/google/apis/core/base_service.rb:366:in `execute_or_queue_command'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client-0.52.0/generated/google/apis/drive_v3/service.rb:918:in `create_file'
```

Comment: Please include the error message

Comment: why not go with google drive v3?

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve this by changing the client options to have a longer timeout period.

```
service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new

  service.authorization = authorize('drive_token.yaml',Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE)
  service.client_options.send_timeout_sec=12000
  service.client_options.open_timeout_sec=12000
  service.client_options.read_timeout_sec=12000
```